# WPF ListBox прокрутка по кругу

Tags: wpf, listbox

Требуется сделать так, чтобы ListBox прокручивался по кругу, не важно как вверх, так и вниз.
Это необходимо для реализации TimePicker'а как в UWP (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/time-picker).

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: Не понятно что вы имеете ввиду, вам нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки вниз перебор выполнялся по кругу? Или чтобы все элементы прокручивались циклически при каждом нажатии?

Comment: Необходимо чтобы прокрутка шла по кругу. Имея исходную коллекцию {1,2,3,4} при прокрутке пользователь должен видеть 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3.... Такое поведение как раз реализовано в UWP версии TimePicker при выборе часов или минут. И в UWP для этого дела есть специальная панель LoopingSelectorPanel, а в WPF такого нет :(

Comment: Ну можно нарыть исходники и портировать панель на WPF. Ну или просто написать аналог с нуля самостоятельно